# _OCIArrayDescriptorAlloc not found during ROracle installation

Tags: r, roracle

I am trying to install the `ROracle` library but I get this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ROracle’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so, 6): Symbol not found: _OCIArrayDescriptorAlloc
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so
```

I tried to follow different approach like [this](https://www.ecourse.org/news.asp?which=3233) but nevertheless I can't fix it.

I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and R version 3.5.1.